# Windows 7 installer doesn't recognize NTFS partition

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to install windows 7 on my Macbook.

I've created NTFS partition, but when i'm starting up Windows 7 installation, it says that i can't install windows on this partition, since drive already contains maximum amount of partitions with this filesystem type.

I haven't heard of any limits on filesystems, but still i can't even format this drive from Win7 installer.

I've found access to command line from win7 installation CD, but i can't find fdisk there to format.

Do you have any idea on about how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Most disks have a "disk label", also called "partition table", at the very beginning. The most common one is **[MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning)**, also called "MS-DOS" (which introduced this particular type).

The MBR allows no more than *four* "primary" partitions on disk. When more is needed, a special "extended boot record" is created as the fourth partition, and it points to as many "logical" partitions as needed.

Even today, Windows only can boot from a primary partition, not from a logical one.

---

> I've found access to command line from win7 installation CD, but i can't find fdisk there to format.

```
diskpart
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do much win 7 till now, but if You have 4 primary ntfs partitions, that could become a problem. Windows usually doesn do a fifth or install into a fifth. How many partitions of what type do You have?